# Как узнать настройки полученные по DHCP

Tags: linux, ifconfig

Как узнать все настройки, полученные по DHCP? Используя ifconfig, я вижу только ip и маску:

```
user@userMashine:~$ ifconfigeth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55        inet addr:192.168.1.12  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0      inet6 addr: fe11::21e:6822:33d0:ca41/64 Scope:Link      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1      RX packets:59775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0      TX packets:45671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000       RX bytes:56757034 (56.7 MB)  TX bytes:4480189 (4.4 MB)      Interrupt:47lo    Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1      RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0      TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0       RX bytes:1040 (1.0 KB)  TX bytes:1040 (1.0 KB)
```

Хотелось бы увидеть шлюз по умолчанию, первичный и вторичный DNS сервера , имя компьютера в сети.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`route` — маршрут до шлюза, `uname -a` — имя компьютера.

Ну и DNS:

```
 > cat /etc/resolv.conf
 nameserver ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх
 nameserver ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх`
```

Comment: этот способ ненадёжен, resolv.conf может не модифицироваться и быть заполнен не параметрами соединения. route так же.

Answer (score 4):

Немного поправлю.

route cработает не везде, а вот

```
netstat -rn | grep default
```

выдаст подобную строку, независимо от системы (linux или bsd)

```
default            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX    UGS         0 163089273   bce2
```

где `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` и будет адрес дефолтного шлюза

Ну, а определить dns-сервер (ибо в случае с dhcp он может не быть прописан в resolv.conf), который резолвит для вас имена можно с помощью команды

```
nslookup ya.ru
```

> Server:         XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
>
> Address:        XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>
> Name:   ya.ru
>
> Address: 87.250.250.203
>
> Name:   ya.ru
>
> Address: 213.180.204.3

где XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX и есть IP вашего DNS-сервера.

Comment: netstat -rn | grep default на ubuntu ничего не выдало

Comment: ну если не сработало netstat -rn | grep default, то попробуйте просто netstat -rn, возможно что у вас просто нет дефолтного маршрута (ну или он отображается без слова default, что было бы конечно странно)

Comment: Почему странно? Как раз так и отображается:Destination Gateway Genmask Flags MSS Window irtt Iface0.0.0.0         31.133.95.253   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth00.0.0.0         31.133.95.253   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth031.133.92.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 eth0169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0

Comment: ну согласно этим данным у вас вообще дефолтный маршрут прописан дважды (который на 0.0.0.0). Это не нормально по-моему. Я бы удалил их, а потом снова прописал дефолтный

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/* :)
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Есть более надёжный способ, используя NetworkManager.
Можно написать свой скрипт и положить его в папку `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` в котором перехватывать нужные события передаваемые через параметры командной строки, и при этом парсить переменные окружения, содержащие в том числе и параметры DHCP для соответствующих событий.
Для исследования, можно создать простейший скрипт:

```
echo "==============" >> test.log
echo $@ >> test.log
declare >> test.log
```

Исследуя его вывод, вытаскивать необходимое и использовать по назначению.

Answer (score 0):

cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.(intrface_1,2,3(eth or enp...)).leases

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

DNS and network info:

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

Answer (score -2):

В Ubuntu:

```
cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?